# How would you solve for Permutations of 3 digit even numbers less than 400 from 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5? (repetition disallowed)

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

If the first digit has 4 possibilities (0, 1, 2, 3)

The second digit also has 4 possibilities (6 - 2 that are already taken)

Then how many possibilities are there for the last digit?

It seems like it would be 3 (0, 2, 4), but how do you take into account the possibility than 0 or 2 has been used for the first digit but at the same time there is a chance that they weren't.

Comment: A number such as $025 = 25$ is not considered a three-digit positive integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to start with the restriction that the number must be even.  Then we have two cases to consider, depending on whether or not the units digit is $2$.

The units digit is $0$ or $4$:  Then there are three choices for the hundreds digit since it must be a positive integer less than $4$ and four choices for the tens digit since it cannot equal the hundreds or units digits.  Hence, there are
$$3 \cdot 4 \cdot 2$$
such numbers.

The units digit is $2$:  Then there are two choices for the hundreds digit, as it must be $1$ or $3$, and four choices for the tens digit since it must differ from both the hundreds and units digits.  Hence, there are
$$2 \cdot 4 \cdot 1$$
such numbers.

Since these two cases are mutually exclusive and exhaustive, there are
$$3 \cdot 4 \cdot 2 + 2 \cdot 4 \cdot 1 = 24 + 8 = 32$$
three-digit positive even integers that can be formed from the digits $0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5$ without repetition.